# Wordpress admin not changing language

Tags: wp-admin, language

I'm struggling to get a nb_NO version of the wordpress admin interface. Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed latest wordpress from wordpress.org
- Moved installation from root to wp/ - site working fine
- Edited wp-config.php to define('WPLANG', 'nb_NO');
- Went to wp-admin and clicked "Re-install now" on the 3.5.1–nb_NO update.

The update runs with no errors, but the admin is still in english. I've tried with different languages as well with the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Moving the wp core to wp/ should not brake the language installer..?

Comment: Are the correct language file in `wp-content/languages/`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Couldn't find the language files anywhere so that got me thinking Wordpress is having trouble writing the files to the languages folder. I posted my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had changed the 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' directory, and Wordpress did not have writing permission to the new content folder, so it couldn't create the 'WP_CONTENT_DIR'/languages folder.

After creating the languages folder in my new WP_CONTENT_DIR directory Wordpress did the language upgrade successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**See**

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language

Try download this package

http://nb.wordpress.org/

If its not working. This package should obtain Norwegian language.