# How can I have different langauges in wp-admin on a multisite installation?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

Changing the admin language for a single installation is easy. But I'm wondering, how can this be done for a multisite installation?

By default it's English, but a customer would like to have it in Norweigan.
[I found this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97935/wordpress-admin-not-changing-language), but doesn't help my case.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Have you seen [Install additional language packs for WordPress](http://marketpress.com/2014/install-additional-language-packs-for-wordpress/)?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin I have authored (Transposh) have this as a side effect, if you have the proper language files installed, and you set the default language using the plugin, the admin interface will change to that language.

Alternatively you can create a function that will change the locale based on the site you are currently on, this isn't too difficult either.

Good luck,